# how fetch 3 radiobutton in radiogroup?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, listadapter, radio-group

How I can adapt this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602426/listview-with-checkbox-radiobutton-textview-and-button-not-working-correctly-in) with 3 `Radiobuttons` i want to fetch all the selected `RadioButtons`  in my listadapter.

Comment: you can iterate your listadapter and check the radiobutton isChecked value. Let me know if this works.

Comment: how i can do this plz

Answer (score 0):

Create a radio group like this.

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioChild1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioChild1" 
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioChild2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioChild2" />

   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioChild3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radioChild3" />

</RadioGroup>
```

inflate this layout to your custom adapter

Use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to get the selected values from the list.

```
ArrayList<String> selectedCheckBox = new ArrayList<String>();

YourView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if(isChecked)
            {
                selectedCheckBox.add(values);
            }
            else
            {
                selectedCheckBox.remove(values);
            }
    }
});
```

For more details refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911361/how-to-get-selected-list-items-from-a-listview-with-checkbox-and-custom-adapter)

Comment: i have listadapter(size=10) with 3 radio for every line

Comment: Values may be anything. ID or text(string) of the list item.

Comment: is not work !! i have listadapter(size=10) with 3 radio for every column

Answer (score 0):

Layout file should be :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/grp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="op1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="op2" />

   <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="op3" />

</RadioGroup>
```

ArrayAdapter should be :

```
private class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected RadioGroup radioGroup;
}

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;
    HashMap<Integer, RadioButton> mapRadioBtnsSelected;
    ArrayList<View> arrViews;


    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        mapRadioBtnsSelected = new HashMap<Integer, RadioButton>();
        arrViews = new ArrayList<View>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grp);
            viewHolder.radioGroup.setTag(position);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            arrViews.add(convertView);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
                    if(mapRadioBtnsSelected.containsKey(getPosition))
                           mapRadioBtnsSelected.remove(getPosition);
                     mapRadioBtnsSelected.put(getPosition, arrViews.get(getPosition).findViewById(checkedId);
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class Model {

    private String name;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

mapRadioBtnsSelected contains the list of selected radio buttons.

Comment: thanks for reply but convertView end chekedid cannot be resolved